# Search - How to change default boolean operator from AND to OR

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, display-template

I believe this is controlled by the Search Box Display template, but I'm not 100% sure.  Does anyone know?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not controlled by the Search Box.

SharePoint search engine supports the operators below. It is by design and the operators cannot be changed. It is impossible to change the AND to OR.

[image]

[Learn more about SharePoint search Keyword Query Language](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference)